# How to fill a grouped, proportional ggplot2 barplot with a third categorial variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Using ggplot2, I want to fill the bars of a barplot that shows the relative frequencies of one categorial variable (i) in two differently sized groups (g = "A", "B") with a third categorial variable (f). The bars within each group should sum up to 100%.

Here's a reproducible example and what I've tried so far:

```
set.seed(7)
g <- sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3)) 
i <- sample(c("C1", "C2"), 100, replace=TRUE)
f <- sample(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5))
df <- data.frame(g, i, f)


p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=i, y=stat(prop)))+
  geom_bar(aes(group = g, fill = f))+
  facet_grid(~g)
p1
```

However, the "fill" command has no effect on this plot (all grey bars).

Hence I tried some code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086575/ggplot2-problems-with-using-prop-and-grouping-bar-graph-by-another-categor), that creates groups using 2 variables. The resulting barplot comes close to what I want, is filled by the third variable, but now the percentages do not add up to 100%, resp. 1:

```
p2 <- ggplot(example_df, aes(x=i, y=stat(prop)))+
  geom_bar(aes(group = interaction(g, f), fill = f))+
  facet_grid(~g)
p2
```

Altough [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478138/barplot-with-ggplot-2-of-two-categorical-variable-facet-wrap-according-a-third-v) sounds very similar, applying the code to a stacked and grouped barplot only reproduces my problems stated above.

Any help appreciated - a pure ggplot2 solution would be awesome, though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe computing the proportion in a `dplyr` pipeline can be useful:

```
set.seed(7)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
g <- sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3)) 
i <- sample(c("C1", "C2"), 100, replace=TRUE)
f <- sample(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5))
df <- data.frame(g, i, f)
#Data
df %>% group_by(i,g,f) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  group_by(i,g,.drop=T) %>%
  mutate(Prop=N/sum(N)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=i))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',aes(y=Prop, fill = f))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  facet_grid(~g)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A shorter alternative is to use `count` and `position_fill`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(g, i, f) %>%
  ggplot(aes(i, n, fill = f)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Allan, for this elegant one. Yet, I want to keep the height of the C1 and C2 bars variable, showing their relative frequencies within each group A and B. I.e. I'm looking for a stacked barchart. This works, but I wondered if there's a pure ggplot solution:

`s1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>%
  summarise(n_group = n())

df %>% 
  count(g,f,i) %>% 
  left_join(s1, by ="g") %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/n_group) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(i, pct, fill = f)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~g)`